# React component library, how to correctly bundle fonts with rollup

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, rollup

I'm working on a project which has a React component library, and a Next JS app which imports said library. I've read a lot of questions on SO and attempted most of the solutions to no avail.

We have the component library working, fonts and all, and in storybook looks great

There's two fonts we import in our package.json (in devDependencies)

```
"@fontsource/inter": "4.5.12",
"@fontsource/material-icons": "4.5.4",
```

The material-icons font is imported in our `<Icon />` component

```
import "@fontsource/material-icons";
```

And referenced in the tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,mdx}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ["Inter", "ui-sans-serif", "sans-serif"],
      heading: ["Inter", "ui-sans-serif", "sans-serif"],
    },
```

This works in storybook with no problems

[image: Storybook menu option with icon]

But when imported into the Next JS app and the same component used

[image]

The files seem to be available in the node_modules folder of the Next JS app
[image]
[image]

Here is the roll up config:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
      json(),
    ],
    external: [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "@fontsource/inter/400.css",
      "@fontsource/inter/600.css",
      "@fontsource/inter/700.css",
      "@fontsource/material-icons",
      "react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css",
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "@fontsource/inter/400.css",
      "@fontsource/inter/600.css",
      "@fontsource/inter/700.css",
      "@fontsource/material-icons",
      "react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css",
    ],
  },
];
```

**QUESTION:** what I'd ideally like to do is export all the referenced css from the component library, such that in the next app's _app.tsx I can use

```
import "@us/component-library/styles.css";
```

***How do I configure rollup to bundle the referenced css and expose it in the build folder?***

**Also:** if there is an alternative or better way of doing this, we aren't precious over the plugins used and would be open to being shown a better (or correct) way of doing this.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: any luck? same boat

Comment: @MattWilde - changed up what we were doing, ended up importing the referenced fonts in a css file and then manually copying the css out of node modules. I will post my solution later. But not sure it's perfect as overriding the font seems more difficult now (e.g. if we wanted to use a different font from the calling app).

Comment: @MattWilde - posted my solution below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still in the same boat - here's how I solved it in the end...

New rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import pkg from "./package.json";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      json(),
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: "node_modules/@fontsource/inter/files/*",
            dest: "./dist/files",
          },
          {
            src: "node_modules/@fontsource/material-icons/files/*",
            dest: "./dist/files",
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  },
];
```

Then in src/theme/input.css

```
@import url("../../node_modules/@fontsource/inter/400.css");
@import url("../../node_modules/@fontsource/inter/600.css");
@import url("../../node_modules/@fontsource/inter/700.css");
@import url("../../node_modules/@fontsource/material-icons/index.css");
@import url("../../node_modules/react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
...
foo {
  bar...
```

Then in our consuming Next app, I no longer have to have the `@fontsource/font` import in the package.json.

In my head, this works because the rollup build, using `rollup-plugin-postcss`, leverages the css imports and bundles everything together as part of the css, rather than trying to re-package imports or manage external dependencies from the consuming app.

Pretty sure my rollup config can still be trimmed down, in particular where I'm using `rollup-plugin-copy` to copy the `@fontsource/font` files. But for now this is working and means our consuming apps don't need to care about importing fonts.

However, this has is drawbacks as I'm not sure how this would work if we wanted to override the font.

Perhaps re-defining the `inter` font in the calling app? And then assigning something else to it?

Or maybe overriding the `fontFamily` in our tailwind config? Not sure yet. Will update when I have a better answer.

Hope this helps someone else - when I get more time to spend on trimming the rollup config I'll post the latest.

Kia Ora!